# C++ extern function error: too many arguments to function

Tags: c++, function, extern

I have a `cw.h` file with a bunch of extern functions in it that I want to call from my `cw.cpp` file.

They are expressed like this in the `.h`. file along with the declarations of the `Type` struct (just example functions, not the actual names of the functions):

```
extern Type* new_type(), match(), sharetype();
```

But their definitions and implementations are in the `cw.cpp` file.
Each of the functions has 1 or more parameters passed into it.

When I try compiling, I keep getting this error message for each of the functions:

```
cw.h:11: error: too many arguments to function Type new_type()
cw.cpp:575: error: at this point in file
```

I have no idea how to fix it. And I've been searching for the past hour (-_-)

EDIT[SOLVED]:

I changed my code in the `.h` file to match the types of the parameters being passed into the functions when they're being called.
No more errors.

Comment: please show cw.cpp for more complete answers. The gist of your problem is your declaration and definitions do not match. As declared they are void functions which don't take any parameters so even 1 is too many arguments. Listen to your compiler ;-)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In C++, a function declared with `()` is a prototype and means that the function takes no arguments. In C++ it is equivalent to using `(void)`. It doesn't have the same meaning as in C (i.e. that the function takes an unspecified number of arguments).

Comment: So all I needed to do was add `void` inside the parentheses?

Comment: @Lady_ari: No, you need to supply the _correct_ prototype for the functions. As I don't know how they are defined, I can't tell you what this is.

Comment: so adding in the types of the parameters being passed in to the functions?

Comment: @Lady_ari: Well, strictly the types that they are defined as taking, but essentially, yes.

Answer (score 0):

Extending CharlesBailey's answer:

In C++, `Type* new_type()` is a different function than `Type* new_type(int)` due to overloading.

Your parameters need to match their definition:

```
//hpp:
extern Type* new_type(int), match(float), sharetype(char);

//cpp:
Type* new_type(int x) {
  // ...
}

Type* match(float x) {
  // ...
}
```